# Sinch authentication by application server issue

Tags: android, authentication, sinch

I am trying to change our client app (Android) authentication method from the simple ApiKey + Secret authentication to the more advanced authentication supported by application server.

The Sinch documentation tells you to remove the Secret from your Sinch client builder code. Thus my code now looks like this:

```
mSinchClient = com.sinch.android.rtc.Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(applicationContext)
            .applicationKey("API_KEY")
            .environmentHost("SINCH_SERVER")
            .userId("USER-ID")
            .build();
```

But this actually results in an exception that says my applicationKey is empty:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.where.the.hell.are.you.BackgroundClientService@a7f29518 with Intent { cmp=com.where.the.hell.are.you/.BackgroundClientService }:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: applicationKey is empty
```

It looks like a bug in the Sinch SDK but maybe I am missing something else here?

I am using the Sinch SDK VERSION 3.2.3 for Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug in the Sinch Android SDK which has been resolved in a new release, v3.2.4 available here: http://www.sinch.com/downloads/